# Using python-for-android, how can I have a service stop itself?

Tags: android, python, android-service, kivy

I am writing an Android application using Kivy that creates an Android service that persists after the graphical part of the application closes. When the app is reopened, it communicates with the service that already exists. My question is: how can I close the service when it is done, since chances are the app will not have a reference to the original AndroidService object?

Comment: Do you know what kind of service you're planning on using?  Some handle that for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but I'm creating the service using python-for-android [link](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/#service-android-service). The AndroidService class has a stop() method, but after I close and reopen the app, I don't have a reference to the AndroidService anymore. The code in my service/main.py stops when it's supposed to, but I'm left with a running Android service that doesn't do anything.